# sql- move log file to another drive

Tags: sql-server

i'm working on huge DB, and while insert\work with big files, log file increase to 60GB and over, and eat all my drive so it can't continue processing.
i tried shrink log file but it work afterwards, and while working it increase again so i thought to move the log file (only) to my 2nd drive where i got more space.

i tried by Detach and Attach but it didnt work , error :

> An error occurred when attaching the database(s).  Click the hyperlink
>   in the Message column for details.

i also tried manually by alter command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [databasename]
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = filename , FILENAME = "new file location and name");
```

but it make the DB "recovery pending" and i had to restore it back from backup.

any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Since you restored from backup, you can add the `MOVE` command to your restore command to move the log file to a new drive during the restore.

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [YourDatabase] FROM DISK = 'c:\mssql\backup\Full.bak' 
WITH CHECKSUM, 
MOVE 'YourDatabase_Log' TO 'E:\newdir\Log.ldf', 
RECOVERY, REPLACE;
```

In order to keep your log file from growing too much, you need to  increase the frequency of your log backups, assuming you aren’t on `SIMPLE RECOVERY MODEL`. Shrinking without backing up is not going to do much, if anything at all. When you backup a log file, the committed transactions are backed up and cleared from the log, freeing up space. As you have witnessed your log file will continue to grow based on the workload. Thus, regular shrinking of the log file isn’t really going to help you.